# Creating Table Website

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working on a website and I am required to convert it to an old table website.

Here's I got my actual site and It's using the regular div so on this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k3ox895w/4/

while here I attempted to use tables: https://jsfiddle.net/k3ox895w/5/

I converted it to table but it all messed up. Not sure what I need to edit to make it look the same like the actual div site like the image you see here:

[image]

Here's the HTML site of the DIV site:

```
<header class="main-header" id="header">
    <h1 class="name"><a href="#">ROSSS</a></h1>
    <ul class="main-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
<div class="banner">
    <h1 class="headline">BONG</h1><span class="tagline">MIKE</span>
</div>
<section>
    <h2>Features</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item-1 col">
            <i class="fa fa-address-card fa-5x"></i>
            <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item-2 col">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-5x"></i>
            <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item-3 col">
            <i class="fa fa-folder fa-5x"></i>
            <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item-4 col">
            <i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-5x"></i>
            <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item-5 col">
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-5x"></i>
            <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item-6 col">
            <i class="fa fa-podcast fa-5x"></i>
            <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="about">
    <h2 class="white">Hello</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitaHELLOta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<footer class="main-footer">
    <div class="footer-inner">
        <span>&copy; 2017 CSS Layouts</span>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And in this HTML, I converted it to Tables:

```
<table class="main-header" id="header">
  <tr>
   <td><h1 class="name"><a href="#">ROSS</a></h1></td>
   <td> <ul class="main-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul></td>
  </tr>

</table>


<table class="banner">
<tr>
        <h1 class="headline">BONG</h1><span class="tagline">MIKE</span>
</tr>
</table>


<table>
<tr>
<th><h2>Features</h2></th>

<td class="item-1 col">
                <i class="fa fa-address-card fa-5x"></i>
                <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

<td class="item-2 col">
<i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-5x"></i>
                <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</td>


<td class="item-3 col">
<i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-5x"></i>
                <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</td>


<td class="item-4 col">
<i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-5x"></i>
                <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</td>

<td class="item-5 col">
<i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-5x"></i>
                <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</td>

<td class="item-6 col">
<i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-5x"></i>
                <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
</table>


<table class="about">
<tr>
<td class="col">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</td>

<td class="col">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
</td>

</tr>

<tr class="main-footer">
<td class="footer-inner"><span>&copy; 2017 CSS Layouts</span> </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

How can I convert it from DIV to TABLES properly? Using the existing CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although table are not recommended for web (harder to maintain later) i hope you have a good reason to use it. You were missing table data (td's) for the header section and you forgot to place the rows in the right place.

I would suggest using a program like Dreamweaver if you are not comfortable with coding tables by hand, one missing HTML element will ruin the look.

Below is the code that i have done to fix things up.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.5;
 margin: 0;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

p {
 font-size: 1.2em;
}

h1{
 font-size: 4em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2{
 font-size: 2.8em;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 40px 0px;
 
}

.center{
  text-align: center;

}

i.fa{
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 color: #34495E;
}


.white{
color: #fff;
}

h2, h3,
a {
 color: #34495e;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
}



a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

table,th{width:100%;}

/* ================================= 
  Base Layout Styles
==================================== */

/* ---- Navigation ---- */

.name {
 font-size: 1.35em;
 margin: 0;
}

.main-nav {
 margin-top: 5px;float:RIGHT;
}
.name a,
.main-nav a {
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 color: #fff;
}
.main-nav a {
 font-size: 1em;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-nav a:hover {
 color: #18bc9c;
}


/* ---- Layout Containers ---- */

.main-header tbody {padding: 1em 0.7em;}
.main-header tbody, .main-header tr {width:100%;}
.main-header td {width:50%;}
.main-header h1{float:left;}
.main-header ul{float:right;}
.main-header ul li{float:left;}

.banner,
.main-footer {
 text-align: center;
}
.banner {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #18bc9c;
 padding: 6.5em 0;
 margin-bottom: 32px;
}
.col {
 padding: 0 1.9em;

}
.main-footer {
 background: #d9e4ea;
 padding: 2em 0;
}


#header{
  width: 100%;
 background-color: #34495e;
}

/* ---- Page Elements ---- */

.logo {
 width: 256px;
}
.headline,.tagline {
 margin: 0;
 color: #fff;
}

span.tagline{
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

.feat-img {
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.col {
   flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 30px);
   margin: 15px 5px;

}

img { 
    width: 100%;
}


.about{
 background: #18bc9c;
 margin: 90px 0px 0px 0px;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 30px 0px;
}


.primary{
 flex-grow: 2;
}



/* ================================= 
  Base Styles
==================================== */

body {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 min-height: 100vh;
}

.row {
 flex: 1;
}

/* ================================= 
  Media Queries
==================================== */

@media (min-width: 769px) {

 /*.main-header,*/
 .main-nav,
 .row {
  display: flex;
 }

 .main-header {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
 }


}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {

 .main-header {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }
```

```html
<table class="main-header" id="header">
  <tr>
   <td class="title"><h1 class="name"><a href="#">ROSS</a></h1></td>
   <td class="nav"> <ul class="main-nav">
   <li>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
   </li>
  </ul></td>
  </tr>

</table>


<table class="banner">
<tr>
<td>
  <h1 class="headline">BONG</h1><span class="tagline">MIKE</span>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table>
<tr>
<th><h2>Features</h2></th>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="item-1 col">
    <i class="fa fa-address-card fa-5x"></i>
    <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

<td class="item-2 col">
<i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-5x"></i>
    <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</td>


<td class="item-3 col">
<i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-5x"></i>
    <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="item-4 col">
<i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-5x"></i>
    <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</td>

<td class="item-5 col">
<i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-5x"></i>
    <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</td>

<td class="item-6 col">
<i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o fa-5x"></i>
    <p class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
</table>


<table class="about">
<tr>
<td class="col">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</td>

<td class="col">
 <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
</td>

</tr>

<tr class="main-footer">
<td class="footer-inner" colspan="2"><span>&copy; 2017 CSS Layouts</span> </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Hope this is what you were after.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Two things.

1st one is the top navigation. Is there any way i can move the link to the right just like the div style site?

See screenshot: http://prntscr.com/f8a7if


Next is the footer:

See screenshot: http://prntscr.com/f8a7nm

As you can see its busted compared to the original div design.

Comment: i have updated the code, is that what you were after?

Comment: Here's what you've done: http://prntscr.com/f8ah2f
It must be like this: http://prntscr.com/f8ah7x

Comment: i changed the code a little, are you using my code or yours? I removed the flexbox part for the top table.

Comment: Good to hear! Accept the answer ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144298/discussion-between-gaara-itachi-uchiha-and-syfer).

Answer (score 0):

For top navigation bar you'll need a css like the following:

```
.main-nav {
    margin-top: 5px;
    list-style: none;
}
.main-nav  > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
  }
```